# i want to verify if the passport(image) submitted by user is white background in php

Tags: php, html, css, image, imagick

i'm using imagick to get the background color of an image
here is my code

```
$imagick = new Imagick();
$imagick->readImage($_FILES['passport']['tmp_name']);

$imagePixelColor = $imagick->getImageBackgroundColor();

$color = $imagePixelColor->getColorAsString();
```

but is not working as expected it keeps on given me srgb(255,255,255) for all images i used as sample. i have used an image with black background but still gives me srgb(255,255,255). pls help

Comment: That method returns the background color so set by `setImageBackgroundColor() ` or the default, which is white. It doesn't scan your existing image to determine a "background" color in the sense that you mean.

Comment: Not using this myself, but it seems a bit ancient to me. In the old days (A.D. 1653) you could add some background color value to an image a program could (read browser) use for GIF/PNG as the alpha channel color (often green,pink,cyan) and determine what pixels were 'transparent'. Even older: top/left (or bottom/right) pixel of each image had the same function. So, if you want to use it for transparency set/get the **image** alpha channel.

Comment: Interesting concepts @RenevanderLende